# remove pdf stamp that has been added by pdftk

Tags: linux, pdf, pdftk

Question: **Can you remove a stamp added with pdftk, using Linux command line tools?**

Motivation for the question:

I have tens of thousands of scanned pages, in hundreds of pdf files.

I would like to stamp each page with some string, for example
`<filename> page <n> of <m>`.

I plan to use pdflatex to create for each file a "stamp file", containing the same number of pages, on each page just the appropriate string (on a white colorbox, i.e., not on transparent background, so that the string is visible even if it happens to be printed on a black part of the scan).

Then I plan to use, for each file `pdftk file.pdf multistamp stamp.pdf output result.pdf`

However, I am worried that sometimes relevant information on the page may get overwritten by the string. I would have hoped that the "stamp" created this way would be identified as stamp in acrobat reader (then you could, e.g., choose whether to print it or not in the print dialog). But this does not seem to be the case. So at least I would be happy to know that the stamp can be easily removed afterwards.

Of course I would also be grateful for suggestions for smarter alternatives. (E.g., is there a Linux command line tool that generates pdf annotations/stamps that are identified as such in acrobat reader?)